# Java Iteration: Hashtable vs HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable, iteration

Why do I get different results when I run equivalent code for hashtable and hashmaps?

```
Iterator<Integer> it = ht.keySet().iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    i = it.next();
    System.out.println(i + " : " + ht.get(i));
}
```

ht is a hashtable object. If i replace with hm, a hashmap object, it doesn't print the values from get() method instead prints null. Why is that?

Comment: Are you sure, that you did not forget to switch the objects at initialization? Specifically, that you put the objects into ht, but try to retrieve them from hm?

Comment: The difference must come from some other reason. Try to output simply `ht.toString()` for comparison.

Comment: I don't get different results when I run a more complete test case . (well, I get different orderings).  Would you post the full code that you used?

Comment: Sorry folks, I switched iterator usage at one point which produced bad results. Rectified it, thanks for the comments!

Comment: @dryHump: Could you post an answer with your "solution"?

Comment: @Paulo the code was the same for hashmap too except that I forgot to change the 'i' appropriately hence was confused. Sorry for the trouble I caused...

Comment: @dryHumping: Yes, I understand this ... but could you post this as an answer (not a comment) and later accept it? I don't want unanswered questions lying around which are in fact already solved.

Comment: It prints `null` (HashMap) because you try to get the value corresponding to the key `i`. Which does not exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While not technically an "answer" to your question (which is not possible due to insufficient code provided in the question), I do have this suggestion regarding code style.

This would have helped you avoid the bug you found in your code (according to your later comment).

The code you provided:

```
Iterator<Integer> it = ht.keySet().iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    i = it.next();
    System.out.println(i + " : " + ht.get(i));
}
```

is equivalent to this more elegant [foreach](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) loop over the [entry set](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29):

```
for (Map.Entry<Integer, Object> entry : ht.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " : " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Use this form in preference to using the iterator directly if you can.
It's neater, and `less code == good`

Answer (score 1):

I think with a HashMap you have to get the entrySet.  Then, you can loop over each Entry...

Here's a ref on iterating a HashMap:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.util/HashMapentrySet.htm

I agree with your initial train of thought though - not sure why it works this way...

Comment: You can do this, and it's more efficient, but there's no reason keySet() + get() shouldn't work.

Comment: @David - thanks for this - I'm new to Java and had issues w/ keySet similar to Dry's...  I've been using entrySet ever since...  apparently to my benefit, but for the wrong reason :)